# Rails 4 Postgres query error

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, model

Here is my code, error comes back with an error at or near WHERE

```
first_of_month = Date.current.beginning_of_month
last_of_month = Date.current.end_of_month
today = Date.current
query = quotes.where('close_date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND status_id = 8 WHERE quote_exp < ? ', first_of_month, last_of_month, today)

query.sum(:total)
```

Comment: Why do you have a `WHERE` clause within your `where()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanatory comments, you could write the query like this:

```
query = query.where(<<-EOQ, first_of_month, last_of_month, today)
  close_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
  AND (quote_exp >= ? OR status_id = 8)
EOQ
```

That will give you: (1) everything from the month (2) that is either not expired or has status 8. Remember that `A->B` is also `~AvB`.

Comment: This I feel is what I am looking for. I will plug it in and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 0):

Your 4th line should not contain the `WHERE` keyword. You should replace it with `AND` if your intent is to add the other criterion to the rest, like so:

`query = quotes.where('close_date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND status_id = 8 AND quote_exp < ? ', first_of_month, last_of_month, today)`

Comment: your second `AND` would set it to only include quotes that close within that period and have a status_id of 8 `AND` and expiration date before today... right? I'm trying to select all between the period and `if` there are expired ones before today, then include them only if they have a `status_id = 8`

Answer (score 0):

You could write it better in this way.

```
query = quotes.where(close_date: first_of_month..last_of_month, status_id: 8).where('quote_exp < ?', today).sum(:total)
```

Comment: I'm trying to select all quotes with a close date between the period and if there are expired ones before today, then include them only if they have a status_id = 8. Would this do that?